# How to randomly settext in textviews in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 string arrays,each of these array's length is 4. I also have four textviews . Now I want to randomly settext of that array's indexes in the textviews. I have done this:

```
ansone.setText(Answera[0]);
anstwo.setText(Answerb[0]);
ansthree.setText(Answerc[0]);
ansfour.setText(Answerd[0]);
```

but its keeps the same sequence every time I run the application, I want to randomly select the arrays in different textviews like some time 'ansone' textview will set the text of Answerb[0], or 'anstwo' textview will set the text of Answerd[0] and so on. Thus everytime I run the application the textviews will randomly select the arrays from where it will be set text. How can I make it random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an ArrayList array:

```
ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
tmp.add(Answera[0]);
tmp.add(Answerb[0]);
tmp.add(Answerc[0]);
tmp.add(Answerd[0]);
```

And then shuffle it:

```
Collections.shuffle(tmp);
```

Next, just put the result to each textviews:

```
ansone.setText(tmp.get(0));
anstwo.setText(tmp.get(1));
ansthree.setText(tmp.get(2));
ansfour.setText(tmp.get(3));
```

Comment: I posted the same as you, right after, so I deleted it... the only change was that I used `List<String> answers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(AnswerA[0], AnswerB[0], AnswerC[0], AnswerD[0]));` to create the array.  Other than that, same answer :)

Comment: It happened, a lot. I too, removed my duplicate answer when someone created faster than me:D